# How do I prevent TGZ archives from being automatically un-gzipped upon download?

Tags: macos, safari, preferences

I use Safari on Mac OS Lion, and one behavior I find rather annoying is that it insists on automatically un-gzipping TGZ archives when I download them. It doesn't *untar* them; it just uncompresses them, which is virtually useless. Ideally, it wouldn't uncompress them at all, but if it would uncompress and untar them I could live with that.

I'm aware that I can uncheck the "Open 'safe' files after downloading" option in Safari to false, but that also means giving up such niceties as PDFs automatically opening when I download them. Is there a more tailored solution?

Comment: PDFs typically open in the browser, regardless of that setting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uncheck the, "Open "safe" files after downloading" checkbox in Safari's General preferences.

[image: Safari Preferences]

Answer (score 1):

You can create a file that overrides OS X's safe file types. [Instructions here](http://www.davinian.com/os-x-leopard-are-you-sure-you-want-to-open-it/). Keep in mind that this is a white list, so you'll have to add the [identifiers](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/UTIRef/Articles/System-DeclaredUniformTypeIdentifiers.html) for file types you *do* want Safari to automatically open.

*Note: these instructions are a bit old, and I can't confirm if this is still the case with Lion and Safari 6 (only on an iPad at the moment), but its worth a try*.